# How to put image next to a paragraph for mobile. Responsive Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-website

I am looking for something along the lines of the below for my website where even in the mobile layout, I want a small thumbnail of an image next to the text:

[image: a]

However, the default bootstrap behavior on mobile is to flow all the divs one underneath the other. The img seems to go full width and text flows underneath it which is not desirable.

Is there something built into bootstrap that will allow me to achieve the desired result or would I have to use some custom CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured I would answer my own question from a year ago seeing it has been viewed over a thousand times. I can then also mark it as answered.

In Boostrap v3, which is built from mobile up, there are classes for mobile devices ".col-xs-*" which will let you specify content that will sit side by side instead of stacking.

One could obviously create these media queries or styles if they are working without Bootstrap 3 or on an older version of bootstrap 3. Refer to the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) or code.

Answer (score 0):

> Bootstrap styles are based on grid system, you don't need to write
>   custom styles for this. You can use span classes to achieve your
>   requirement

If you are using fluid layout you can use something like this

```
<div class="span6">
  <div class="span6">
     here your image code
   </div>
   <div class="span6">
     here your description
   </div>                  
  </div>
</div>
```

If you are using fixed layout

```
<div class="span6">
  <div class="span3">
     here your image code
   </div>
   <div class="span3">
     here your description
   </div>                  
  </div>
</div>
```

You can choose the **span class** as per your page width

### Update:

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wLxen/3/

For more information http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Comment: At mobile widths, Twitter Bootstrap's own website breaks down into columns stacked on top of each other instead of following the grid pattern http://cl.ly/image/1H3I3m030M0x

Comment: I think you have to customize it, with using CSS media queries http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: I tried adding custom css with media query to reduce the image to a smaller size and float it but I am having little success with it. http://jsfiddle.net/yashrg/wLxen/1/

Comment: oh, that is quite opposite of the effect I was going for… http://cl.ly/image/0F0J2p222G33 I don't want the image to be that big or stack on top of the text.